# Change colour for "git reflog"

Tags: git

Is it possible to change the colour of the hash in `git reflog`?  The one it's using right now is hard to read.  I tried the following in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[color "reflog"]
hash = red
```

I also tried `ref` and `reference`.  I am using git 2.5.1 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `--pretty` to customize the output.
To change the hash to red:

```
git reflog --pretty='format:%C(red)%h%Creset %gD %gs'
```

or to include branch names, relative date of change and author

```
git reflog --pretty='format:%C(red)%h%Creset %gD: %gs %C(yellow)%d%Creset %Cgreen(%ar) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

see `git help log` for more format options.

Comment: In the example in this answer, use `%gD` instead of `-` to get the reflog selector in the usual place and format.

Comment: I added an alias, `rl`, that used your configuration.  Is it possible to create a `reflog` alias for `git reflog`?

Comment: @StephenRasku, how to create an alias for `git reflog` is dependent your OS. On linux, at least, you may add `export grl="git reflog"` to your startup script (I have `export g="git" in my `.bash_aliases`)

Comment: @joran, Oh, I meant a git alias (not a bash alias).  I'm on Linux.

Comment: @StephenRasku, you can have `!sh -c 'git....'` in an alias if it is that you mean.

Answer (score 1):

No great answer here, but [it doesn't appear as though you can configure the color of git-reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).